# Laravel array with illuminate objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass images from AJAX to back-end and upload them, save their names into the database.

My AJAX code:

```
var form_data = new FormData($('.updateForm')[0]);

            $.ajax({

                method: "POST",
                url: "/updateMyPost",
                data: form_data,
                cache : false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    console.log(result);

                }

            });
```

Laravel function to upload the files:

```
public function updateMyPost(Request $request){

        $name = $request->input('text');

        $images = $request->file('images');

        foreach($images as $image){

            $image_name = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = public_path('images');

            $img->move($path,$image_name);

        }  

    }
```

And this is what $request->file("images") gives to me when I print it out.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => images.jpg
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [hashName:protected] => 
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpAB87.tmp
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpAB87.tmp
        )

    [1] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => iphonex-TA.jpg
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [hashName:protected] => 
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpAB88.tmp
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpAB88.tmp
        )

)
```

How can I get each image name and also upload them?

Comment: are you uploading multiple images?

Comment: Yes in this case two images

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are uploading multiple images so your `store()` method should like below

```
public function updateMyPost(Request $r)
{
    $images = $r->images;
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $path = $image->store('public/images');
        $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        // to store data in your table
        Model::create([
          'path' => $path,
          'name' => $image_name
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the function name have to be 'store'? My function has a different name and your code doesn't do the job.

Comment: it doesn't matter function name can be any thing.it is just an example

Comment: in your code change this `$img->move($path,$image_name);` to `$image->move($path,$image_name);`

Comment: I have removed `$image = $image->toArray();` line and also changed `$img->move($path,$image_name);` to `$image->move($path,$image_name);` and it works now. Thanks a lot!